# Way to configure system properties for EJB?

Tags: ejb, substitution, message-driven-bean, system-properties

Maybe a duplicate question, however, I did not find any answer to it.
I have an MDB, I'd like to configure some system properties in descriptor files, these properties must be available during deployment.
where should I put these property name-value pair? Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I think you can do that with your application server, which one do you use?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to deal with JBoss EAP5. I can set them from mbean SystemPropertiesService and add this mbean as a dependency to the Queue service.